# Excel vba formula string doesn't calculate: #NAME? error

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have this sub that types in a sum formula in A1 cell:

```
Sub test_string()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Cells(1, 1) = "=СУММ(B1:D1)"
End Sub
```

At first it looks like it has worked, but when I open a worksheet there's a `#NAME?` error in A1 cell:

[image]

The error disappears when I manually calculate the formula (put cursor in formula's text and click Enter).

Why does this happen and is there a way to fix it? I tried

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Cells(1, 1).Calculate
```

But to no result.

Comment: You forgot an `=` so `"=SUM(B1:D1)"` (Although I would not think that would result in #NAME ...)

Comment: @Alex K. Sorry for confusion, it's the result of retyping. The error isn't because of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not specifying which property of Cells you want.

The default property of Cells is Value. Therefore when you write:

```
Cells(1,1) = "=SUM(B1:D1)"
```

... what you're actually saying is:

```
Cells(1,1).Value = "=SUM(B1:D1)"
```

You need to use the .Formula property:

```
Cells(1,1).Formula = "=SUM(B1:D1)"
```

Comment: or `Cells(1,1).FormulaLocal = "=СУММ(B1:D1)"` if you prefer.

Comment: @CLR I heard it wouldn't work on Excels with a different language version. I have a Russian Excel version, so I guess `FormulaLocal` wouldn't work for someone with an English Excel isntalled on?

Comment: That would make sense. I hadn't realised you were looking to use this on other set-ups.